# Vue throwing error when passing null Laravel model value as a prop

Tags: laravel, model, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to call an object as a prop. `Auth::user()->car` is my Car model however it can be null.

Now, in vue, I am trying to pass it to my component:

```
<my-comp :car="{{ Auth::user()->car }}"> </my-comp>
```

If Car object exists, it works. However, if it is null, vue throws an error

> [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in

I know I can return `$car` using `return view()->with(..`, however I am curious why this approach is not working and what I am doing wrong.

---

Other ways I tried:

```
<my-comp :car="{{ Auth::user()->car ? Auth::user()->car : null }}"> </my-comp>

<my-comp car="{{ Auth::user()->car }}"> </my-comp>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use an empty string the template will fail to compile.

You're not setting an empty string with `<my-comp :car=""></my-comp>`.

The correct way is: `<my-comp :car="''"></my-comp>`.

Recall that `v-bind` expects javascript expressions.

so you could try:

```
<my-comp :car="{{ Auth::user()->car ? Auth::user()->car : 'null' }}"> </my-comp>
```

and then you can decode that null string in vue

Comment: But `Auth::user->car` is an Object, not a String; and I can confirm with dump (`dd()`) that, it fails when object value is null

Comment: Thats all fine, I am just telling you why its failing to compile when there is no object provided. And I would say that prolly you want to bind better formatted data from backend to a vue component, so that way it will be much easier for you to work with!

Comment: You are right, 'null' actually worked without throwing any errors

Comment: Yes :) ! Better bind some good formated json rather than an object like that! But your choice, I answered what was asked I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved above problem using 
json_encode($yourobject).

```
json_encode($yourobject);
```

if you need to change on vue component,

```
<my-comp :car="@json(Auth::user()->car)"> </my-comp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass entire Car object in car property ? or it's just a name for car?

if you want name than it is string and for that you need to attach ' like I mentioned below:

```
<my-comp :car="'{{ Auth::user()->car ? Auth::user()->car : null }}'"> </my-comp>
```

and if it's object than you need to call a method in Mounted() method of Vue component and fetch the Car object using Axios.

Comment: It is the Car object instead, not string. When object is null, it throws the error. (I don't think it matters but I use Laravel Spark)